# How to make gtk_window_set_position of gtk work?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to set the position of the window using  `gtk_window_set_position`

but it seems that after the window is created, the `gtk_window_set_position` will not take               effect.
I'm wondering how to call `gtk_window_set_position` after the window shows up, i.e. a button event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wrote a minimal working example that implements two approaches. One approach uses `gtk_window_move` and the other `gtk_window_set_position`.

If you have the gtk+ reference at hand the code should be self explanatory.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

void
button1_clicked_cb (GtkWidget * widget, GtkWindow * window)
{
    GdkWindow *root;
    gint width, height, rwidth, rheight;

    gtk_window_get_size (window, &width, &height);
    root = gtk_widget_get_root_window (GTK_WIDGET (window));
    gdk_window_get_geometry (root, NULL, NULL, &rwidth,
                             &rheight);

    gtk_window_move (window, (rwidth - width) / 2,
                     (rheight - height) / 2);
}

void
button2_clicked_cb (GtkWidget * widget, GtkWindow * window)
{
    gtk_widget_hide (GTK_WIDGET (window));
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET (window));
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *button1;
    GtkWidget *button2;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("approach 1");
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("approach 2");

    box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), button1, TRUE, TRUE,
                        10);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), button2, TRUE, TRUE,
                        10);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
                      G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (button1, "clicked",
                      G_CALLBACK (button1_clicked_cb),
                      window);
    g_signal_connect (button2, "clicked",
                      G_CALLBACK (button2_clicked_cb),
                      window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thannks for the reply, the `gtk_window_move ` works, but there is still a problem, when I move the window to somewhere and use `gtk_window_set_position`, it doesn't show in the center(best try more than once).any reason why this happens? thanks again.

Comment: it seems that `gtk_window_set_position(center)` is only triggered once, how can I make it work more than once?

Comment: I showed a work-around in my example (look at `button2_clicked_cb`) that works at least with my window manager. Maybe `gtk_window_set_position` set's an application window property that is  interpreted by the window manager only once. `gtk_window_move` seems to trigger an actual request to the window manager. Unfortunately i can only speculate about it.

Comment: I've tried `gtk_window_set_position(mouse)`, and it works fine. `gtk_window_set_position(center)` just doesn't work. maybe it's something about the center position. And is there any other way to set the center position or I can only use the `gtk_window_move` to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Trying the answer from 2013, as mentioned in the comments, I found that gtk_window_set_position may work the first time or two, but then stops working.

Also gtk_widget_get_root_window is deprecated now (2023).

While experimenting for my own needs I refactored the 2013 code to remove the unreliable **gtk_window_set_position**,
to use **gdk_screen_get_root_window** instead of the deprecated **gtk_widget_get_root_window**
and to move the window to the top right corner which I needed, rather than the centre of the screen.

In case it's helpful for anyone this is what I ended up with:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

void button1_clicked_cb(GtkWidget *widget, GtkWindow *window)
{
    GdkWindow *root;
    gint width, height, rwidth, rheight;

    gtk_window_get_size(window, &width, &height);
    // Debug:
    printf("Width: %d Height: %d\n", width, height);

    // Get the default screen
    GdkScreen *screen = gtk_widget_get_screen(widget);

    // Get the root window of the default screen
    root = gdk_screen_get_root_window(screen);
    gdk_window_get_geometry(root, NULL, NULL, &rwidth, &rheight);

    // Center the window on the screen
    // gtk_window_move(window, (rwidth - width) / 2, (rheight - height) / 2);

    gint xindent = width + 25, yindent = 10;
    // Debug:
    printf("RootWidth: %d XIndent %d\n", rwidth, xindent);
    gtk_window_move(window, rwidth - xindent, yindent);

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *button1;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 70);

    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Move Window");

    box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), button1, TRUE, TRUE, 10);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (button1, "clicked",
        G_CALLBACK (button1_clicked_cb), window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

I also found another way to get the screen size:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Initialize GTK
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // Get screen size
    GdkRectangle workarea = {0};
    gdk_monitor_get_workarea(
        gdk_display_get_primary_monitor(
            gdk_display_get_default()), &workarea);

    // Debug:
    printf("Screen Width: %u, Height: %u\n", workarea.width, workarea.height);
```

By the way, to compile these I used:

```
gcc -o move_window move_window.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```